# Selecting checkout button using selenium python did not work

Tags: python, selenium

For the following html, my code could not select the checkout button, what's wrong going with it?

My code:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('checkout').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="Proceed To Checkout"]')
```

Html:

```
<div id="itemBasketButtons" class="clearfix">

    <input id="updateOrder" class="button" type="button" value="Save Changes"></input>
    <input id="checkout" class="button" type="button" value="Proceed To Checkout »"></input>

</div>
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element

Comment: Do you use both lines of the code? I. e. first one fails with the Exception too?

Comment: i tried them one by one

Comment: Fix the html first. Try to remove closing `<input>` tags because they are redundant

Comment: while automating the web based ordering process, the new browser opens automatically in which i have to select "Proceed To Checkout »

Answer (score 0):

```
value="Proceed To Checkout »"
```

Note that "»" sign at the end. You probably should use

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(u'input[value="Proceed To Checkout »"]')
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 33: invalid start byte

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element

Comment: while automating the web based ordering process, the new browser opens  automatically in which i have to select "Proceed To Checkout »

Answer (score 0):

Can you find element itemBasketButtons?

```
browser.find_element_by_id('itemBasketButtons')
```

If so, try to select it, and then the second child (the checkout button)

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#itemBasketButtons:nth-child(2)')
```